# Use of cloud computing in web development

Tags: cloud

Could anyone please tell me what the web developers can do with cloud computing, sorry for the very basic question i got confused so much by googling. Please tell me how to use or where to use this technology in PHP web development field. I used AMAZON'S ec2 but there i just followed their manual and it was very simple file storage. But in what way it could help me to make great projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a developer, most of the times you rather want to spend your time on creating your 
applications and services without messing around too much with the scalability and deployment issues (though it has it fun parts too)
Cloud computing platforms provides you with a stack of solutions that can ease and speed up your development cycle letting you consume resources as a service and pay only for what you use so in most times it can be very cost efficient

One of the most important things that i can find in cloud computing is that you can terminate many cases of a single point failure and bottlenecks in a convenient way
the services are highly available, you can scale up and maintenance resources easily!

for example with amazons web services, you can

- host your sites on an EC2 instances
- share and distribute your data on S3
- manage a distributed database with SimpleDB or RDS
- use SQS or SNS for distributing messages and notifications
- maintain and meet capacity of demands for content using CloudFront

and all this with several easy to handle API calls...

so as a bottom line you can create many great projects using those solutions, i can say for sure that cloud based development (and MapReduce) fulfilled a lot of my needs and contributed to the way i develop fast, highly scalable and reliable services

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. its really convincing answer to me to go around this.

Answer (score 1):

Web applications developed using cloud computing (e.g. google app engine) offer inherent scalability. Also, application developers need not have to worry about the hardware setup, hosting and maintenance. Being in cloud the web applications also ensure high availability.

Comment: yeah those are the example apps and advantages over cloud computing. but my doubt is my management ask me to use a package called wikivideo with the cloud computing. i dont know what way to start it. thats why i got the basic doubt. thanks for your reply @gopi